# Intel UEFI firmware hiding operating systems depending on boot order

Tags: linux, boot, uefi, qubes

I have installed Qubes OS R4.0 onto my Intel NUC which came with Windows 10. After I did so, it booted straight into Qubes and the Windows option disappeared from the firmware's boot menu (accessible by pressing F10).

I then attempted to alter the boot order to boot Windows first.

There are two other Windows entries shown by `efibootmgr -v`, which look very similar but not identical - `efibootmgr -D` did not remove any of them, so they were not duplicates. So I put all of those entries first in the boot order - I suspect one is the "real" Windows, the second is the "auto-repair" thing which runs when Windows fails to boot a few times, and the third is the OEM thing that runs when the auto-repair thing fails.

Now the NUC boots into Windows 10, and Qubes is nowhere to be seen on the boot menu!

I suspect this is down to Intel's ham-fisted attempt to hide the two "recovery OSs", which probably relies on boot order rather than naming (since they are both named Windows 10).

I am not sure what the original boot order was before I installed Qubes - there are a couple of other options as well, like "hard disk" (infinite recursion??) and network boot.

How can I (a) boot back into Qubes, and (b) make it possible to select between Windows and Qubes on bootup?

Answer (score 0):

[Install rEFInd](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html) and reboot. Select Windows (which was the leftmost option on the top row for me) to boot Windows or Qubes Xen [some version number] (which was the rightmost option on the top row for me) to boot Qubes.